# enforce pull/push of master branch when releasing with git flow

Tags: git, git-flow

When releasing a new version using `git flow release finish 0.1.7` the local master branch gets updated regardless of whether it is up to date or not. Furthermore the new master branch does not get pushed to our central repository (gitlab) after the release.

This led us to some difficulties in the past. We had merge conflicts in the master branch when someone forgot to pull the master branch before releasing a new version and pushing it afterwards. Then the local history of the master branch looked something like this

```
0.1.2 --> 0.1.6 --> 0.1.7
```

while the master branch on the central repository contained the following tags:

```
0.1.2 --> 0.1.3 --> 0.1.4
```

So, the new versions 0.1.6 and 0.1.7 were missing in our central repository while the developer didn't see 0.1.3 and 0.1.4 in its local repository.

Is there a way to enforce the following commands before running `git flow release`:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout release-0.1.7
```

and calling this afterwards:

```
git checkout master
git push
git checkout develop
```

Any idea?